# Html.fromHtml not working

Tags: android

I have a textview and I want to display 0.0 in normal fontSize of the TextView and then the StringResult() in a smaller text size.

If I add "0.0" + it's not working. Why?

```
public String StringResult(){
String displayLbl = this.getResources().getString(R.string.displayLbl);
TextView myUnitLbl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_unit_res);
String myFinalLbl = displayLbl + " " + myUnitLbl.getText() + " ";
return myFinalLbl;
}


public void cmd_rst(View v){
TextView lblText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblresult);
lblText.setText("0.0" + Html.fromHtml("<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>"));
}
```

Comment: `lblText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>"));  //only this works`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because the `Spanned` returned from `Html.fromHtml` gets used as a normal String (thereby loosing any formatting) when you try to concatenate it with "0.0". To make this work, pass the whole stuff into `fromHtml`:

```
Html.fromHtml("0.0<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>")
```

The same principle applies in more complex cases:

```
lblResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("%.1f", myCalc) + " " + "<br>" +
    "<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>"));
```

Comment: YES. It was simple, thanks. But how about in this case more complex? 

`lblResult.setText(String.format("%.1f", myCalc) + " " + "\n" + Html.fromHtml("<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>"));`

Comment: Thanks Henry!

It was pretty obvious that I had to include everything under Html.fromHtml() as you suggested.

Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1):

just

```
Html.fromHtml("0.0<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>")
```

changed to

```
Html.fromHtml("0.0<small>" + StringResult() + "</small>").toString()
```

Because fromHtml() method takes argument of Spanned type not String type.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get that. `Html.fromHtml()` returns a `Spanned`, if you call `toString()` on it the formatting will be lost.